# advice on embedded linux on an FreeScale SoC MCU MPC56xx

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux, powerpc, system-on-chip

I wan't to port linux to a MCU EVB  the mcu is freescale MPC5604P,
   is there some advice on how to do that?
   or some web site we can start on ?

Note: Cpu is an [e200z0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerPC_e200#e200z0), PowerPC.

Comment: http://kernelnewbies.org/ should be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not feasible to run Linux on this device.  It runs at 64MHz and has 512Kb of on-chip flash and 64kb of on-chip SRAM and no external memory interface. Linux required more like 4Mb/256Mb and will be a bit sluggish below 200MHz especially with respect to boot time.

You would use this device with either no OS or a simple RTOS. Freescale's product page lists [EB tresos AutoCore OS](http://automotive.elektrobit.com/home/ecu-software/autosar/eb-tresos-product-line/eb-tresos-autocore.html) and [EB tresos Safety OS](http://automotive.elektrobit.com/home/ecu/functional-safety.html).  Boot time of a typical RTOS would ne measured in milliseconds or less.